# Getting null parameter in DB when persisting through JSF+EJB application

Tags: jpa, primefaces, ejb

I'm creating my first  `JSF+EJB` application test, when I insert basic data in a jsf form a click on `<p:commandButton/>`,  the tasks are done correctly except for one input. in the form I have  2 input fields, #1 is set to `VARCHAR` in my db.table and  #2 is  `INT` but they are both `<p:inputText/>`. with their correspondand `EL`.

When verifying the information persisted in DB, only  field #1 is persited correctly, #2  is set to   and I don't understand why.

I've done previous applications where I use `Hibernate` for persistence and this works fine, am I  missing some  `Annotation` or something in the `@EJB` module?

here is my code:

```
<h:form>
        <p:panelGrid columns="2" >                
            <p:outputLabel value="Owner"/>
            <p:inputText value="#{accountMB.account.ownername}"/>
            <p:outputLabel value="Balance"/>
            <p:inputText value="#{accountMB.account.balance}"/>
        </p:panelGrid>
            <p:commandButton value="Create Account" action="#{accountMB.commandButton()}" ajax="false"/>        
    </h:form>
```

ManagedBean:

```
    @ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class AccountMB {

    @EJB
    private AccountFacade facade;
    private Account account;

    public AccountMB() {

    }
    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        this.account = new Account();
    }

      // setters .. getters ... 

    public String commandButton(){
        facade.openAccount(this.account.getOwnername(), this.account.getBalance());
        return "response?faces-redirect=true";
    }
}
```

session bean:

```
    @Stateless
public class AccountFacade extends AbstractFacade<Account> {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "bankAppPU")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return em;
    }

    public AccountFacade() {
        super(Account.class);
    }

    public Account openAccount(String ownername, int balance){
        Account ac = new Account(balance, ownername);
        em.persist(ac);
        return ac;
    }
    public void closeAccount(int accountNumber){
            Account ac = em.find(Account.class, accountNumber);
            if(ac != null)
                em.remove(ac);            
    }
    public void deposit(int accountNumber, int amount){
            Account ac = em.find(Account.class, accountNumber);
            if(ac != null)
                ac.deposit(amount);
    }
    public int withdraw(int accountNumber, int amount){
            Account ac = em.find(Account.class, accountNumber);
            return (ac != null)? ac.withdraw(amount): 0;
    }
    public List<Account> listAccounts(){
         return em.createNamedQuery("Account.findAll").getResultList();
    }    
}
```

Entity bean:

```
  @Entity
@Table(name = "account")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Account.findAll", query = "SELECT a FROM Account a")})
public class Account implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "BALANCE")
    private Integer balance;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 100)
    @Column(name = "OWNERNAME")
    private String ownername;

    public Account() {
    }

    public Account(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Account(Integer id, String ownername) {
        this.id = id;
        this.ownername = ownername;
    }
// setters ..  getters ..                     
    public void deposit(int amount){
        this.balance += amount;
    }
    public int withdraw(int amount){
        return (amount > this.balance)? 0 : (this.balance-=amount);
    }      

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<p:inputText value="#{accountMB.account.balance}" converter="javax.faces.Integer" />
```

or

```
public String commandButton(){
        facade.openAccount(this.account.getOwnername(), Integer.parseInt(this.account.getBalance()));
        return "response?faces-redirect=true";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

After printing `balance`  in several places of the application, turns out my   mistake  was in the  Database  itself, for I had set accidentally `BALANCE INT(11)` so   any  bigger number than  the format it was set to  would be set to `null`.